# Android Display a date of the week

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-date

i want to display the days of the week with the date of that week. 
Like today, i want to display for my calendar is like this:

```
Mon  Tues  Wed  Thurs  Fri  Sat   Sun
8    9     10    11    12   13    14
```

Then, when it another week starts, the numbers changes..
So, i experimented with the android calendar class. So i came out with this:

```
TextView[] tx = {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7};

    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd"); 
    GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
    String[] dateStringArray = new String[7];

    for (int day = 0; day < 7; day++) {
        dateStringArray[day] = curFormater.format(date.getTime());
        date.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, true);
        System.out.println("HELLO WORLD DAYS: " + dateStringArray[day]);
        tx[day].setText(dateStringArray[day]);
    }
```

just to check if i can attain my objective. Well, it is close to what i want.
The problem is, for example today is Saturday, the output is this:

```
Sat   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thur   Fri
13    14    15    16    17    18     19
```

Then, tomorrow..i'm guessing this would become

```
Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thur   Fri  Sat
14    15    16    17    18     19   20
```

So, the starting day changes.
Is there a method/s that will help me attain my objective. Maybe i've missed that 
out while reading the document. Please
Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: may be use this method calender.get(calender.DAY_OF_WEEK) get the today week

Comment: yes, i've also tried that one. it gave me the days of the week but, it started on saturday. The output goes this way:
`sat-13  sun-07  mon-08   tues-09  wed-10   thu-11   fri-12`
it is very close.. but saturday ruined it..

Comment: @elL Check my answer.. I have tested, it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd"); 
        GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
        String[] dateStringArray = new String[7];
             date.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, date.get(GregorianCalendar.DATE)-date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
        for (int day = 0; day < 7; day++) {
            dateStringArray[day] = curFormater.format(date.getTime());
            date.setFirstDayOfWeek(day);
            date.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, true);
            System.out.println("HELLO WORLD DAYS: " + dateStringArray[day]);
        }
}
```

Comment: hmmm. it starts on Saturday (maybe because today is Saturday??).
even though i added this `date.setFirstDayOfWeek(GregorianCalendar.MONDAY);`
the result would be

`sat-06 sun-07 mon-08 tues-09 wed-10 thur-11 fri-12`  ..hmm

Comment: `date.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, date.get(GregorianCalendar.DATE)-date.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)+1);`  add +1 at the end so the out will be dates from  `07 08 09 10 11 12 13` and the first day is 7